# Checkbox Horizontal Alignment using BootStrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, thymeleaf

I have a Thymeleaf/Bootstrap 3 view that contains the following piece of code to iterate my list of checkboxes and displays them vertically:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group-lg col-xs-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="facilities">Facilities</label>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
      <div th:each="facility : ${facilities}">
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
        <label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I would like to display the checkboxes in groups of 3 horizontally like this. Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use Css column to do this. simple. use this code below:

**Updated** Check this live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cepL14vc/1/)

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row">
  <div class="form-group-lg col-xs-5">
    <label class="control-label" for="facilities">Facilities</label>
    <div class="form-group-lg">
      <div th:each="facility : ${facilities}" class="column_2">
        <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
        <label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}"></label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css:

```
.column_2{
    -webkit-column-count: 2; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 2; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Sarower Jahan

Answer (score 1):

if you are not worried about order, you can just float the checkboxes. You need to add a `div` before every checkbox according to bootstrap documentation example (see [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms)).

The HTML should be like this:

```
<!--not worried about order-->
<div class="row no-order">
<div class="form-group-lg col-xs-5">
<label class="control-label" for="facilities">Facilities</label>
<div class="form-group-lg clearfix">
<!--if this is your looped div, then you can just put the class "checkbox" in here-->
  <div th:each="facility : ${facilities}"> 
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    1</label></div>

    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    3</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"> <label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    4</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    5</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
   6</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS:

```
.no-order div.checkbox{
   float:left;
   width:50%
 }
```

BUT, if you need to maintain order (2 after 1 and NOT on the side of 1) and want a pure CSS solution, then you're screwed in terms of browser support, because you have to use `columns. see canIUse here: http://caniuse.com/#search=columns . I suppose jQuery/Javascript solutions can be found that will give you better flexibility.

HTML (order maintained - pretty much the same, except `checkbox-group` gets added):

```
<div class="row ordered">
<div class="form-group-lg col-xs-5">
<label class="control-label" for="facilities">Facilities</label>
<div class="form-group-lg">
  <div th:each="facility : ${facilities}" class="checkbox-group">
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    1</label></div>

    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    2</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    3</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox"> <label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    4</label></div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
    5</label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox"><label class="checkbox-inline" th:text="${facility}">
    <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{checkedItems}" th:value="${facility}" />
   6</label></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and CSS :

```
  .ordered .checkbox-group{
  -webkit-columns: 2 150px;
  -moz-columns: 2 150px;
  columns: 2 150px;
  -webkit-column-gap: 2em;
  -moz-column-gap: 2em;
  column-gap: 2em;
 }
 .ordered div.checkbox{
  -webkit-column-span: all;
  -moz-column-span: all;
  column-span: all;
 }
```

Here's my codepen for this: http://codepen.io/samia92/pen/JKrojB/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how practical it is, but you could nest `columns` around each set of checkboxes and include that inside your iteration or for more control you can float the checkboxes yourself with CSS.

**Nested columns Example:**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <label for="facilities">Facilities</label>

      <div class="row">
        <div th:each="facility : ${facilities}">

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Toilets
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Bar
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Restaurants
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Free WiFi
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Gift Shop
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Free Coffee / Tea
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-xs-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">TV
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Bed
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Something Else
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Input</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">

      <label for="facilities">Facilities</label>

      <div class="row">
        <div th:each="facility : ${facilities}">

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">One
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Two
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Three
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Four
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Five
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Six
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-sm-6">
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Seven
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Eight
              </label>
            </div>
            <div class="checkbox">
              <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="">Nine
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Input</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Or if you want more control you can build a grid yourself just for the checkboxes.

**Floated Checkbox Example:**

```css
div.form {
  background: tomato;
}
div.form .checkbox {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}
@media (min-width: 480px) {
  div.form {
    display: table;
    background: deeppink;
  }
  div.form .checkbox {
    width: 50%;
    display: inline-table;
    margin: 5px 0;
  }
  div.form .checkbox:nth-child(odd) {
    background: dodgerblue;
  }
  div.form .checkbox:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
    background: lightskyblue;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form">

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Toilets
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Bar
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Restaurants
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Free WiFi
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Gift Shop
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Free Coffee / Tea
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Free WiFi
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Gift Shop
          </label>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="">Free Coffee / Tea
          </label>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <label>Input</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```